# How to read an xml file as string in vb

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, onix

I'm trying to read from an onix file and save the information onto a mysql database.

I'm able to read titles, country code, isbn and other fields but for some strange reason I cant get short description.

The short description field `<d102><d104>` is embed in html text and when I try to read from it without any alternations it doesnt work and if i tried to save it as a string does the same.

On the database I created a field in the table shortdescription varchar(70) 
and i also, at first thought it was the amount its allowed to stored "varchar(70)" if I increase it, doesn't help!

This is part of an onix feed I'm trying to read

```
<othertext>
      <d102>01</d102>
      <d104><![CDATA[A Course in Behavioral Economics  is a concise and reader-friendly      
introduction to one of the most influential areas of economics today. Covering all core areas of the subject, the book requires no advanced mathematics and is full of examples, exercises, and problems drawn from the fields of economics, management, marketing, political science, and public policy, among others. It is an ideal first textbook for students coming to behavioral economics from a wide range of disciplines, and would also appeal to the general reader looking for a thorough and readable introduction to the subject.

Available to lecturers: access to an Instructor's Manual at www.palgrave.com/economics/angner, containing a sample syllabus,
instructor guide, sample handouts and examinations, and PowerPoint slides.]]></d104>
</othertext>
```

I tried using this code below, the same theory worked for getting the isbn etc.:

```
Function HandleTagName(name as String) as XName 
    Select Case name
        Case "d104", "text"
            If ShortName Then
                Return "d104"
            Else
                Return "text"
            End If
     end select 
end function 

dim xmlDoc as XDocument
dim xr as XmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath(ThisBook.FromFile))
xr.Namespaces = false

dim  document as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
document.Load(xr)
xr.close()
    if not document("ONIXmessage") is Nothing then
        Dim attrColl as XmlAttributeCollection = document("ONIXmessage").Attributes
        attrColl.RemoveAll()
    end if

xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(document.OuterXML)

Dim Products As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

if xmlDoc.DocumentType is Nothing then
     ShortName = True
else
     if instr(xmlDoc.DocumentType.ToString(), "/short") then
          ShortName = True
     end if
end if

Products = from product in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(HandleTagName("Product"))

For Each ThisOtherText In product.Elements(HandleTagName("OtherText"))
    If ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("TextTypeCode")) = "02" Then         
        If ThisBook.shortDescription = "" Then 
           ' if you say 
           ' dim xxx as string = "test"
           ' ThisBook.shortDescription = xxx

           ThisBook.shortDescription = ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("Text"))
        End if 
    End If
Next
```

I'm not sure if its something i'm not doing right in the code or is it something to do with how i declared shortdescription on the database

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, i'll keep that in mind but it does work. My problem is reading the short description

Comment: @user3142046 Hi, I m doing the same. But before, I wonder how ou structured your MySQL ? There is lot of roles, codes, etc. Did you find a structured one somewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, is all you want to do read a .xml file into a VB.NET string?

```
Imports System.IO
...
Dim xmlfilereader as streamreader = new streamreader("locationofxmlfile.xml")
dim xmlfilestring as string = xmlfilereader.read()
```

xmlfilestring is now a string containing your XML file. Is that all you wanted?

Comment: I would like to read CDATA as string. If I should say:                 dim shortd as string = "test"                                          ThisBook.shortDescription = shortd                                    on the database, in the shortdescription field I can see the word "test", but when i try to save it as I would do for isbn             dim shortd as string = ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("Text")) ThisBook.shortDescription = shortd                                      it doesnt work. My question is how to save CDATA as a string in vb.net

Comment: Ok. I'll reply as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following XML (just in case, below is a valid VB.NET declaration):

```vb
Dim xml = <othertext>
            <d102>01</d102>
            <d104><![CDATA[A Course in Behavioral Economics  is a concise and reader-friendly      
introduction to one of the most influential areas of economics today. Covering all core areas of the subject, the book requires no advanced mathematics and is full of examples, exercises, and problems drawn from the fields of economics, management, marketing, political science, and public policy, among others. It is an ideal first textbook for students coming to behavioral economics from a wide range of disciplines, and would also appeal to the general reader looking for a thorough and readable introduction to the subject.

Available to lecturers: access to an Instructor's Manual at www.palgrave.com/economics/angner, containing a sample syllabus,
instructor guide, sample handouts and examinations, and PowerPoint slides.]]></d104>
          </othertext>
```

This:

```vb
xml.<d104>.Value.ToString
```

yields a string:

> A Course in Behavioral Economics  is a concise and reader-friendly       introduction to one of the most influential areas of economics today. Covering all core areas of the subject, the book requires no advanced mathematics and is full of examples, exercises, and problems drawn from the fields of economics, management, marketing, political science, and public policy, among others. It is an ideal first textbook for students coming to behavioral economics from a wide range of disciplines, and would also appeal to the general reader looking for a thorough and readable introduction to the subject.  Available to lecturers: access to an Instructor's Manual at www.palgrave.com/economics/angner, containing a sample syllabus, instructor guide, sample handouts and examinations, and PowerPoint slides.

Is that what you want? If not, please let me know in comments.

Comment: not exactly .... The xml i'm getting is not apart of the code. I'll get an onix file containing all of the xml and then i'm trying to write a program that reads the file and saves it to the database.

Comment: @user3142046: Okay, please elaborate then.

Comment: @user3142046: Oh, it does not matter if it's part of code or not, the above method is a generic approach to handle any XML element. Also - see my edit, I fixed my typo there. Please post any examples in your question, I don't think comment system will show them properly.

Comment: hmm... presently i'm saving short description as string on the database. How exactly would i save the CDATA embedded text as a string in the program?

Comment: @user3142046: Well, I just showed you how to extract a string from CDATA element. Save it to anywhere in the same way you save any other string.

Comment: ok, i'll try saving it with toString but it would end up looking like this: ThisBook.shortDescription = ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("Text")).toString

Comment: @user3142046: Which is fine with me, `<>` is just syntactic sugar. But I still think you want `Value.ToString`, rather than `ToString`. The difference is that just `ToString` will give you an XML node AS IS, whereas `Value.ToString` will give you the contents.

Comment: @user3142046: Please elaborate, I tested the above solution inside VS, and it did work exactly as I described above.

Comment: For Each ThisOtherText In product.Elements(HandleTagName("OtherText"))
    If ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("TextTypeCode")) = "02" Then         
        If ThisBook.shortDescription = "" Then 
           dim shortd as string =    ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("Text"))

           ThisBook.shortDescription = shortd
        End if 
    End If
Next

Comment: You said to try toString so i tried ThisOtherText.Element(HandleTagName("Text")).toString and it still doesn't work.                                                        My program takes an onix file and runs through each line and picks up isbn, title, country code etc. I used the similar coding for each and it works! ... but for some strange reason I cannot save CDATA as string.

Comment: @user3142046: No, I said try `Value.ToString`. Please read my answer or comment carefully. You can publish code on pastebin and give a link to it. Here in comments it's unreadable. Or update your original question (which is a better practice on SO).

Comment: @user3142046: `I cannot save CDATA as string.` Why? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dataset To read XML:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim myString As String
    ds.ReadXml("Your Xml Path")
    myString = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("d104")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say a variable named xmldata is made, containing all of the xml file inside the  tag, as a string. Hopefully you know how to get to that point. From there, you need to split the string into an array based on the '[' character. Use the following line:

```
Dim Openbracketarray() as string = xmldata.split("[")
```

Next, you need to find the CDATA part. Use the below script:

```
Dim locationofCDATA as integer = 0 '0 just in case theres an error.'
For i = 0 to Openbracketarray.length - 1 'loop through all instances of a bracket found in the xml'
If Openbracketarray(i) = "CDATA"
locationofCDATA = i
EndIf
i = i + 1
Next
```

Now, with that location, find the contents of the CDATA string.

```
Dim CDATA as string = Openbracketarray(location of CDATA + 1)
```

But wait, we still have all the jargon at the end. Delete it with another split.

```
CDATA = CDATA.Split("]")(0)
```

This removes the close brackets after the CDATA String.